# Getting Unknown Build error in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

While trying to build a `Xamarin.ios` project, it gives me Unknown Build Error, for iPhone Device.
While Building for Simulator it builds fine.

> The Error i get is somrthing like below.
>   Error: /Users/admin/Documents/projectdirectory/AppName.app: unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff

I am using latest `Xamarin` and Xcode, and MVVM crosslight.

Please help in resolving.

Comment: Check your device that  if  an old version was installed in it,if yes try to delete the old  version and re-try deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with certificate. The app was not able to build properly as it wasn't able to find the certificate.

the issue got resolved by just restarting the machine.